# How to delete first character after table using POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am attempting to format a Word document that has multiple tables. I need to delete line breaks that occur after table. How to i achieve this programatically in Java ?

I am currently trying it with the following code and it does not work

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = xwpfTable.getCTTbl().newCursor();
cursor.toEndToken();
cursor.toNextToken();
cursor.removeChars(2);
```

**Further Clarification :** We are receiving non-formatted word files from external source. We need to eliminate paragraph (extra lines in-between tables) when the table has only 1 row. Currently I are using a macro and achieving this by code :

```
For Each t In doc.Tables
        Set myrange = doc.Characters(t.Range.End + 1)            
        If myrange.Text = Chr(13) Then
            myrange.Delete
        End If
```

Thanks in advance

What I am trying to remove:
[image: What I am trying to remove]

Comment: This question is not answerable as it is now. In `Word` `Office Open XML` line break characters do not have special meaning, as always in `XML`. So it is not clear what exactly you wants to remove. Maybe there is a empty paragraph after the table. But each table needs at least a paragraph after it. So please show a screenshot of what exactly you wants to remove.

Comment: Thanks Axel for responding. Please find the screenshot of what i am trying to delete added in main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot you wants to remove empty paragraphs which are placed immediately after tables.

This is possible, although i am wondering why those paragraphs are there. After removing those paragraphs, in `Word` the tables are not more editable as single tables but only as rows within one table. Is this what you want?

Anyway, as said removing the  empty paragraphs after the tables is possible. To do so, you could traversing the body elements of the document. If there is a `XWPFTable` immediately followed by a `XWPFParagraph` and this `XWPFParagraph` does not have any text runs in it, then remove that `XWPFParagraph` from the document.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordRemoveEmptyParagraphs {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordTables.docx"));

  int thisBodyElementPos = 0;
  int nextBodyElementPos = 1;
  IBodyElement thisBodyElement = null;
  IBodyElement nextBodyElement = null;
  if (document.getBodyElements().size() > 1) { // document must have at least two body elements
   do {
    thisBodyElement = document.getBodyElements().get(thisBodyElementPos);
    nextBodyElement = document.getBodyElements().get(nextBodyElementPos);
    if (thisBodyElement instanceof XWPFTable && nextBodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
     XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)nextBodyElement;
     if (paragraph.getRuns().size() == 0) { // if paragraph does not have any text runs in it
      document.removeBodyElement(nextBodyElementPos);
     }
    }
    thisBodyElementPos++;
    nextBodyElementPos = thisBodyElementPos + 1;
   } while (nextBodyElementPos < document.getBodyElements().size());
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WordTablesChanged.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: This approach worked. Those extra paragraphs were there due to issues in a source system that created these files. After the provided code, the tables appear as a single table(Which is what i wanted). Only issue is when the Apache POI reads the generated file again, these rows are counted as individual tables. Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: @Prasanth P J: Yes, since we are only removing the paragraphs between the tables, in `Word` the tables are not more editable as single tables but only as rows within one table then. But of course the `XML` stays containing single tables as long as one not opens the document in `Word`'s `GUI`, edit the table and resave. Whitout using `Word`'s `GUI` this only could be changed by merging the single table's `XML` together. That would be very laborious.